# Reverse character array without using extra memory

Tags: arrays

I want reverse a character array **without using extra memory** mean to say not to use any **extra variable** and **extra array** and not to use any **built in function**.

For example given array is

> "This is a car"

the output should be

> "car a is this"

I have written piece of code but it gives output like this

> "rac a si siht"
>   Here is code

```
for ($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Can we do this through pointer.I have really tried to do it but i am stuck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "not to use any extra variable and extra array" - but you already used "extra" variable `$i` and array `$arr`.

Comment: Actually $arr is given array.yes i use extra variable but how to do without using extra variable i am stuck with it not getting idea how to do that.

Comment: `$arr` comprised of one element with a single string `"This is a car"` OR each character(including space) is in separate array element ?

Comment: yes actually it is a character array each character(including space) is a separate array element

Comment: you'll not find such extremely "raw" solution without using any variable, also, such simple functions as `isset` and `count` are also built-in

Comment: "Without using extra memory" they most probably meant using O(1) space complexity i.e. without using another array of the same length. 
Without using any other variables does not make sense to ask during the interview because there is no benefits in not using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking without using an additional variable (or by calling out to something else, which will be using an additional variable).

Sounds like homework to me :)

Without giving the whole answer and spoiling your education, maybe you should look at 'split'ing the string on the spaces, then outputting the result of that in reverse?

---

Ok... benefit of the doubt. How about this (assuming it's PHP?):

`str_split(implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(" ",implode($arr)))));`

Pretty ugly, and certainly doing allocations behind the scene, but technically not using any extra variables in your code?

Comment: this is not a homework i was asked this question in interview but did not come up with solution

Comment: It needs at-least one extra (scalar) variable and is easier with two.

Comment: @Dave you are not allow to use any built in function also...can we do this problem through pointers?

Comment: @HassanShahbaz, "you are not allow to use any built in function also" - you should add this requirement to your question beforehand

Comment: Jasen answerwed that part already. You need at least 1... otherwise how are you tracking this 'pointer'?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes sorry for that i forget to mention that in my question.

Comment: Is there no way to do this?
Not to use extra memory,built in function,variable.No a single variable i have searched a lot but could not find any solution.